# jquery Mobile aand Asp.net Button click event not firing and redirecting to back url

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile

I have follwing code

```
    <div class="main" data-role="content">
        <div class="choice_list menuwrapper" >
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li><a href="CreateUser.aspx" data-transition="slidedown" >

                        Create User
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="WebForm1.aspx" data-transition="slidedown">

                        Manage User

                </a></li>
                <li><a href="Default.aspx" data-transition="slidedown">

                        Upload File
                </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
    </div>`
```

but when i try to click any button on createuser or other page the button_click event is not firing in asp.net and the page redirects to default.aspx,
I found when gooogled that using

```
 $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        // jQuery Mobile's Ajax navigation does not work in all cases (e.g.,
        // when navigating from a mobile to a non-mobile page), especially when going back, hence disabling it.
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;

    });
```

it will solve, but no luck in my case,
Could somebosy please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Did you write any code in code behind file?

Comment: yes there is code inside button click event for saving user info...

Comment: Where is runat="server" tag in your link?

Comment: runat="server"  in link didnt help too...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a rather large mobile project. We also ran into other bugs when using .NET masterpages with jQuery Mobile. We ended up not using a masterpage in the end because there were just too many issues.

Try adding `data-ajax="false"` in all of your links. That should be what the code you posted is doing, but it might not be working depending on the version of JQM you're using.